# Meaning of a mirror image of a person suspended in a drop

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, interpretation

"He saw himself in her eyes, suspended in two shining drops of bright water, himself dark and tiny, in fine detail, the lines about his mouth"... p.14 Fahrenheit 451

I know that the verb is often used to mean *to hang*, but it doesn't make sense to replace suspended with hanging in this context... 
I found another definition being: "if small pieces of solid material are suspended in a gas or a liquid, they hang or float in the gas or liquid", and it would make sense that he's floating in the liquid (figuratively speaking), but I'm not certain. Any thoughts?

Comment: "Tears" that were almost about to fall.

Comment: Yes, when I read "suspended" in this sentence, it makes me imagine his reflection floating in the tears in her eyes.